# How to set default language of Xcode's simulators to English from the very beginning?

Tags: ios, xcode, simulator

I used the simulators for a few years running fine with English. Then suddenly one day the language of all simulators changed to the language of my home country.

Even newly created simulators starts with that language. I have to manually go to the Settings of each simulator to change it back to English whenever I create a new one.

I just don't know what happened.

I would like to ask how to bring everything back to English by default?